# Kendo - creating a custom model property with value from server property

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a property called Copies which is defined on the server that represents the default number of copies allowed.   And I can update this value and it will update an input field on my UI.

however,  I would like to be able to reset the Copies property to the original value if the user resets this field on the UI.

My idea was to define a custom property on my kendo datasource model called originalValue that references the Copies property.  but this just seems to override the Copies property if I do something like this.

```
schema: {
            data: 'd',
            total: function (data) {
                return data.d.length;
            },
            model: {
                originalCopies: "Copies"
            }
        }
```

how can I go about creating a custom property like this which is basically a immutable clone of my Copies property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it on the server side, just create a separate property "OriginalCopies" and set it to Copies. Once passed to the client side , it will lose its immutability.
Something similar could be done on the client side as well. JSON.stringify your Copies and set
OriginalCopies to the JSON.parse value of the stringified  variable as:

```
var copies = JSON.stringify(data.Copies);
data.OriginalCopies = JSON.parse(copies);
```

Comment: I was thinking in the case where I might not be allowed to add another property on the server.  But your example here should do the trick, if I just assign "Copies" to a dynamic OriginalCopies property on the data object during the ajax success.  Thanks.